# What is the timestamp format of _hoodie_commit_time column in Apache Hudi?

Tags: apache-hudi

I'm exploring `apache-hudi` framework and following the [quick guide](https://hudi.apache.org/docs/quick-start-guide.html). I'm trying out incremental query functionality, where we use the column `_hoodie_commit_time` for determining the incremental pull. I was wondering what is the timestamp format & time-zone for this column. Could anyone help me out here? Here is an example value of `_hoodie_commit_time` column: **20210730005516**.

Answer (score 0):

_hoodie_commit_time is the machines current timestamp at which the commit action performed. This time is decided on the spark driver.
Monotonically increasing timestamp is of YYYYMMDDhhmmss and timezone is machine's timezone.

Some additional concepts can be found here: https://hudi.apache.org/docs/concepts